# OpenVINO API 2.0 cannot convert non-frozen TF1 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, openvino

I tried to convert TensorFlow 1 CycleGAN non-frozen model with OpenVINO API 2.0 on Windows.

[image]

I used `mo --input_meta_graph cyclegan.model-2002.meta` to convert my model.

But got the following error.

```
[ FRAMEWORK ERROR ]  Cannot load input model: Attempting to use uninitialized value generatorA2B/g_r6_bn2/scale/Adam_1
         [[{{node _retval_generatorA2B/g_r6_bn2/scale/Adam_1_0_218}}]]
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULS43Oo2c2qsxDrDnUZdIT7-NKA3Btq9/view?usp=sharing) is my non-frozen model files.

Update .pb [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15CGnD6hL9KzaNs7HlTBgF_1CqTlRaNPh/view?usp=sharing) I transferred.

After using the following command.

```
mo --input_model A2B_model.pb
```

The error occurred.

```
[ ERROR ]  Exception occurred during running replacer "REPLACEMENT_ID" (<class 'openvino.tools.mo.front.output_cut.OutputCut'>): Graph contains 0 node after executing <class 'openvino.tools.mo.front.output_cut.OutputCut'>. It considered as error because resulting IR will be empty which is not usual
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might be due to uninitialized variables. Initialize all variables and reload the weights. Another possible workaround is to freeze the graph and export it to protobuf (.pb) file.

Comment: For your information, starting from 2021.3, TensorFlow 1 is supported with limitations, additional information can be obtained in Release Notes : https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/openvino-relnotes-2021.html

Comment: I have updated the result that I export to .pb file, but it still fails, please help.

Comment: I've checked your .pb file and only one node is visible. You can view your .pb file using Netron. Can you please check your .pb file, and if possible can you share a valid .pb file here?